# How do I echo an array with json?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

My code does not seem to return JSON for `$_GET['fruitVariety']`, any idea why? 
My DB is correctly set up.

It's like json_encode can only echo 1 array.

```
$rows = array();

if(isset($_GET['fruitName'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT variety FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY variety");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['fruitName']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if(isset($_GET['fruitVariety'] )) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT fruittype FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY fruittype");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['fruitVariety']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: What does $rows have for starters? Can you show us?

Comment: your `$rows` are getting overriden if both are set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding the value you put in `$rows` after the first query. You should do :

```
 $rows[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The brackets (`[]`) are very important ! You can find more information about the proper syntax in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

And actually, I think you only have the values for fruitVariety and not for fruitName ;)

Comment: I made the change, but strange enough I still keep getting blank data for 'fruitVariety' with that solution. I guess there must be something wrong with the jquery script on the frontend. 

Could you guys take a look for me here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191910/loading-json-data-with-jquery-php-and-mysql-for-chained-selectboxes

Thanks in advance!